# Can Excel 2011 and Excel 2016 work from the same macro workbook source on OSX?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This may be extremely specific, but I use macros a lot in my job. We recently got Excel 2016 for Mac in my office, which is universes better than Excel 2011 except for the VBA editor which has taken a huge hit in functionality and ease of use.

Lately, I've been editing macros using my Excel 2011 personal macro workbook then copy/pasting all code over to my Excel 2016 personal macro workbook, which can be a hassle and is prone to error at some point in the future. Is it possible to have 2011 and 2016 source from the same personal macro workbook, so that when I edit in 2011, it automatically changes what is used in 2016?

If someone has a solution for this, this could also potentially be a great way to share regularly updated macros among co-workers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to disappoint you. I don't think this is possible especially because with every change of version (from 2000 to 2003 to 2010 to 2013) there have always been changes in the vba coding. On Mac this is even a bigger issue as they have added and reduced the functionalities over and over again. Also a lot of code that works on office for windows is not working on Mac as the functionality of the Mac OS and the Windows OS are completely different. I have been working on office for Mac 2011 for about 4 months with vba and it has been really hard to create some codes which on windows would have worked easily.

Also would I not recommend doing what you want as functions which may have worked on 2011 may not work on 2016 as they have changed/deletet/recreated functions when changing the Office-Versions before. So this might provide a huge resource for errors.

If I'm wrong with all this I will be happy to learn otherwise :)

But as I said, this is just my point of view and maybe someone more experienced might help you out with a solution.

Comment: Thanks Kathara. What you're saying makes perfect sense. Hopefully with updates 2016's VBA editor gets better over time, but they need some drastic improvements to get to where they were in 2011's version.

Comment: No problem. I have had some problems with vba on mac myself and sometimes it really gets frustrating. Up until now I haven't heard the best of office 2016 (I think for windows) as it seemed that there are a lot of bugs. It would be cool if they could upgrade the functionality of vba on Mac with this version. But I guess we just have to wait and see :) Good luck with your codes anyway.